# How to change the base field of an Alfresco ftl (freemarker) control?

Tags: javascript, workflow, alfresco, freemarker

Im trying to define a very simple ftl as a control to a workflow form field.

This is the code where the ftl is being used:

```
<field id="myTes:myList" set="noderefs" mandatory="true" >

<control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/myFTLExample.ftl" />      

</field>
```

This is the ftl code:

```
<#assign controlId = fieldHtmlId + "-cntrl">

<b>test</b>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

alert("${fieldHtmlId}"); //I can see the generated name of the field

alert(document.getElementById("${fieldHtmlId}")); //returns null

alert(YAHOO.util.Dom.get("${fieldHtmlId}")); //returns null


}

//]]></script>
```

The problem:

I can see the resulting html on my workflow form. The script also executes and I get the first alert. I can see the name of the field as a big string (where parte of that string is the name of the base field: myList.

However, the second and the third alert always returns null. So Im not able to get the base field in order to change/update its value.

What am I missing? Please note that this problem is not related with the async nature of the workflow forms, because, even if I run the script when a user clicks a button (and in this case the DOM is all set... yes I wait minutes for it), I will get null also.

Comment: Are you sure that the id generated in your dom is the same as ${fieldHtmlId} ?

Comment: yes, but I have figured out the problem.

Comment: Ok, could you please post the solution as an answer to your question  so that everyone can benefit ?

Comment: sure! When in Alfresco one associate a ftl component to a field, I thought Alfresco would manage the livecycle of the base field. But that is not true. We need to create that field as an input field inside the control. That is why I was not getting the field... because it was not created. After that I still wasnt able to set the selected data from the table to my base (workflow) field, because I was just setting the id of the field like this: id="${fieldHtmlId}". However, we must also set the name of the input field like this: name="${field.name}". Regards!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is this:

```
<#assign controlId = fieldHtmlId + "-cntrl">

<b>test</b>
<input id="${fieldHtmlId}" type="hidden" name="${field.name}" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

alert("${fieldHtmlId}"); //I can see the generated name of the field

alert(document.getElementById("${fieldHtmlId}")); //returns null

alert(YAHOO.util.Dom.get("${fieldHtmlId}")); //returns null


}

//]]></script>
```

We must always have an input field that will hold the value of the `myTes:myList` field. Also, in order to set the value of this field, we must set the name attribute as in the example.